# How to pass a parameter for a JS function inside .then, or achieve similar behavior?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Let's assume there is a promise *createPost* and a function *getPosts*. The first one creates a recored in a database of posts and resolves.
 *getPosts* retrieves all posts, creates a UL lists and appends it to a webpage.

```
 createPost ({*post contents JSON*})
 .then(getPosts);
```

When createPost is called as above, the promise waits until the posts are updated and -then- *getPosts* is run. However, if for some reason, I want to resolve and then run *getPosts* with a parameter: *getPosts(param)*, it gets triggered right away, before promise resolves.

How (and **why**), can the .then callback function contain a parameter, without breaking out of the promise? Or, how can I achieve this behavior?

EDIT: **Why** is it, that while

```
.then(getPosts(param));
```

does not wait for the function to resolve,

```
.then(() => getPosts(param));
```

does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the root question.  Say you have:

```
function f() {
    return 'hello';
}
```

`then()` takes a function as its parameter.  So saying `then(f)` says "invoke f after the promise resolves.  If you say `then(f())`, what you're saying is "pass the result of invoking f (which is 'hello') to then'. f gets invoked right away.

Also note, incidentally, that the function you pass to then *will* be invoked with a single parameter, namely the resolution of the promise to which `then` is attached. eg:

```
someAsyncFn() {
    /* return a promise that resolves to "foo!!" */
}

someAsyncFn().then(console.log);  // this will log foo!!
```

Though probably poor style, this means you can say...

```
createPost().then(() => param).then(getPosts);
```

**EDIT**

A few more words on when function gets run...

```
// nothing gets invoked when we define a function
function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

let a = foo;  // this doesn't invoke foo.  a is now a function

let b = foo();   // this *does* invoke foo, b is now 'bar'

let c = () => 'bar';  // the same as defining a function. it doesn't invoke anything

let d = c;  // this doesn't invoke c.  d is now a function

let e = c();  // this *does* invoke c, e is now 'bar'
```

Using all that, when we say

```
.then(getPosts)  // this doesn't invoke getPosts

.then(getPosts(params))  // this invokes getPosts and passes the result to then

.then(() => getPosts(params))
```

This last formulation defines a function (unnamed) that when called (which is not yet) will invoke getPosts with params.  When we pass that unnamed function to then, we're saying, "when the promise is resolved, call this unnamed function and this unnamed function will invoke getPosts"

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. Could you also please take a look at the edit of my question?

Comment: Sure.  Do you mean the **why** part?  I was hoping the first code block and paragraph of my answer got to that.   Was it unclear?

Comment: I'm sure you have explained it well. But I still don't understand why _()=>{getPosts(param1, param2)}_ does not get invoked right away, just like _f()_ would.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function that does what you want. Something like this:

```
createPost ({*post contents JSON*})
  .then(result => getPosts(param, result));
```

This code will wait until `createPost`'s promise has resolved, at which time it will call getPosts, passing in `param` as well as the result from `createPost`.

Or if you don't care about the result at all, just that createPost has finished, you could do something like this:

```
createPost ({*post contents JSON*})
  .then(() => getPosts(param));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper inline function.

```
createPost ({*post contents JSON*})
    .then(()=>{getPosts(param1, param2)})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
createPost ({*post contents JSON*})
 .then(getPosts(param));
```

When you do this you are executing `getPosts` method at that instant and passing it's return value as parameter to the `then` method. If you do this instead

```
createPost ({*post contents JSON*})
    .then(function () {
        getPosts(param);
    });
```

You are waiting for the promise to resolve and executing getPosts after the promise is resolved.